# MacOs, Docker-sync, Laravel 5.8, Postman - performance

Tags: laravel, macos, docker, docker-compose, postman

INTRODUCTION

I am using Docker on Mac. I decided to use Docker-sync because bind mounts are slow on Mac. I've managed to successfully set up the whole thing. What I saw after makes me question if it is even worth using Docker on Mac. I hope it is the fault of my setup or something.

CONFIG

docker-sync.yml

```
version: "2"

options:
  verbose: true
syncs:
  appcode-native-osx-sync: # tip: add -sync and you keep consistent names as a convention
    src: '../'
    # sync_strategy: 'native_osx' # not needed, this is the default now
    sync_excludes: ['vendor', 'node_modules']
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./php/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webapp
    image: php:7.3-fpm-alpine
    volumes:
      - appcode-native-osx-sync:/srv/app:nocopy
  apache2:
    build:
      network: host
      context: ./apache2/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: apache2
    image: httpd:2.4.39-alpine
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - appcode-native-osx-sync:/srv/app:nocopy
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:latest
    command: mysqld --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 13306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
      MYSQL_USER: blogger
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: local
  appcode-native-osx-sync:
    external: true
```

PROBLEM (I THINK)

Setting Docker-sync was supposed to make it feel much more like native setup/Linux setup in terms of performance.

I have noticed something that from my point of view makes the entire thing kinda useless.

So here we go.

WITHOUT DOCKER-SYNC

1. I make 1 request via postman(Cache-Control: no-cache) which takes ~6.8s to finish. It is only a few lines of text, nothing else is going on. I am simply getting one dummy, short blog post out of the database and spitting out JSON.
2. If I make subsequent request straight away time drops to ~1.4s per request. If I keep hitting that endpoint it will stay at this level.
3. If I wait a few seconds between requests then the first request after this pause will go back to ~6.8s.

WITH DOCKER-SYNC

1. I make 1 request via postman(Cache-Control: no-cache) which takes ~5.1s (so not much better) to finish. Exactly the same data as last time.
2. If I make subsequent request straight away time drops to ~100ms(sic!) per request. If I keep hitting that endpoint it will stay at this level.
3. If I wait a few seconds between requests then the first request after this pause will go back to ~5.1s.

QUESTIONS

1. What do you think - is this request cached by Docker, Laravel, Postman? I did notice a similar problem at work with Symfony 3.4 but I am not maintaining things like that at work. This is my personal project and my first time so deep inside of the Docker World.
2. Like I mentioned I am using Docker-sync for speed. Usually, when I work it looks like this: write code for a couple of minutes, hit endpoint, repeat. At this point, I am back to ~5.1s and I have to wait - is there any way of solving this problem with the first request being slow like that? Maybe I have misunderstood the idea behind Docker-sync but I was sure it was supposed to help me to keep all the requests I make fairly quick.
3. I personally blame Laravel. Can anyone shed a bit of light on what might be the actual source of the problem here?

EPILOGUE

I did install Linux on my Mac just to try it out on Linux however there are few things that make Linux much less attractive(I love Linux anyway!) when it comes to hours and hours of coding.

UPDATE 21.08.2019

I just did the same test on Ubuntu 18 with Docker... 80ms! (8.8 seconds) / (80 milliseconds) = 110 - this is horrifying!

UPDATE 03.09.2019

I did some tests yesterday - I tried to use different sync strategies - `rsync` and `unison`. It seems like it is not having any effect at all. Does anyone else have the same issue? Maybe we can work on it together?

Comment: I believe this is a problem with mac + docker rather than Laravel. I never used Docker-sync before but saw some people used cached volumes in their compose file. It didn't actually help me much so I didn't check that in for the devs. I'm on the DevOps side, so I package the source into the image instead of the volume mount which is lightning fast on my mac. I think what is making your subsequent requests faster in Laravel is opcache which stores the compiled php code in memory once it has been executed. Unfortunately I don't have a solution for your use case.

Comment: Yesterday I've spent like 4 hours on it and I think this isn't Laravel - like you say it has to be docker on Mac. No matter what I do it just doesn't care about it, just stays slow. I think you are also right about opcache. That's ok I will try a few more times and if nothing comes up I will just stay on Ubuntu until problem is solved. It's a shame though as Linux despite being wonderful system has its downsides. Thanks for your input, much appreciated.